# AngularDegrees^2 and Steradians are incompatible units

Tags: units

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[360, "Degrees^2"], "Steradians"]

AngularDegrees^2 and Steradians are incompatible units
```

What am I doing wrong in not getting 4$\pi$?

Comment: By any chance, are you using `"Degrees"^2`, with the `^2` outside of the string, rather than `"Degrees^2"` ? That's the only way I can get something similar to your error. Alternatively, `"AngularDegrees"^2` and `"AngularDegrees^2"` both work fine.

Comment: No that doesn't seem to be the problem.I even get the error with `UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Steradians"], "Radians^2"]`

Comment: Have tried the below answers with a fresh kernel?

Comment: restarting the kernel after upgrading to Mathematica 12 solved the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you have misspelled "Degrees". When I correct your misspelling, I get

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[360, "Degrees^2"], "Steradians"]
```

> Quantity[Pi^2/90, "Steradians"]

It quite a bit less than $4 \pi$. To find the angular measure of a complete sphere in angular degrees we can do the following:

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[4 π, "Steradians"], "Degrees^2"]
```

> ```
> Quantity[129600/π, ("AngularDegrees")^2]
> ```

Also, note that a steradian is the same as a square radian.

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Steradians"], "Radians^2"]
```

> ```
> Quantity[1, "Radians"^2]
> ```

Comment: Corrected the spelling, but sill getting Quantity::compat: (AngularDegrees)^2 and Steradians are incompatible units

Comment: @Nickpick I can reproduce the result in this answer on MMA cloud. What’s your version and OS?

Comment: I'm still on Mathematica 11, maybe need to upgrade to 12

Comment: @Nickpick I can't seem to reproduce your problem on MMA 12.0.0, see my answer below

Comment: Mathematica 12 solves the problem. Seems to have been a bug in Mathematica 11

Comment: @m_goldberg in one of your conversions, "Degrees" should be "Degrees^2".

Comment: @david. +1 I've corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We can't seem to reproduce your problem.

Here are the results of your simpler question from comments, first on my laptop:

```
$Version
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Steradians"], "Radians^2"]

(* Out: 
"12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)"
Quantity[1, "Radians"^2] 
*)
```

... and on the cloud version:

```
$Version
UnitConvert[Quantity[1, "Steradians"], "Radians^2"]

(* Out: 
"12.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (November 16, 2020)"
Quantity[1, "Radians"^2]
*)
```